# Definition of continuity of operator with range in a set of operators (nonlinear)

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

I have an operator $T:H \to O(H,H)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space and by $O(H,H)$ I mean the space of operators $F$ with $F:H \to H$. We are in the general nonlinear setting.

What exactly would it mean to say that $T$ is continuous? If $h_n \to h$ in $H$, $T(h_n) \to T(h)$ should hold in which norm?

Comment: I do not think that you can define a norm on $O(H,H)$ (unless $H = \{0\}$). Did you try to define a norm on the space of all functions mapping $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$?